# What is the scale of the map of Rokugan?

Tags: maps, l5r-4e, rokugan

Is anyone aware of the scale of the map for L5R? They talk about the sorts of tribulations of travel, but not what sorts of travel times are to be expected for any range and inquiring minds (my table) want to know.

My table has sent a message to an Emerald Magistrate to address an immediate high severity crime and want to know how long it should take for it to get there. They have also been in situations involving timing a mercantile barge, or making it to a specific location by a given moon phase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ISTR d20 Rokugan has a scale bar on the map.

The following image looks to be the same

[image]
From: http://brennor.dyndns.org/~steve/L5R/CombatMaps/map_rokugan.jpg

Comment: That seems to sync up with Simon Gill's answer about the Mantis Island being 45mi.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The problem with the printed maps is that they are Imperial statements and cannot be wrong. If the ground disagrees with the maps then the ground is wrong. How dare it defy the Empress? Of course, if you're late because you thought the map was right, then you're the one at fault.

There is one distance reference that I can find in the write-up of [Toshi no Inazuma](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/Toshi_no_Inazuma) that states that the Island of Silk and Spice it is on is about 45 miles long. This is the west-most of the Mantis islands.

Using it, we can take a guess that CN10 to 18 are about the same 45 miles apart. And from there, you should be able to determine a physical scale with a ruler.

Assuming the Imperial Cartographers are right about the distance between Toshi no Inazuma and Dojo Raiden that is.

Comment: That could turn out to be very useful, actually.  Do you happen to know of anywhere it lists travel times?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything Rokugan specific. Overland travel speed normally averages 3-4 miles per hour (even on a horse because of the amount of rest they need). Relays can travel faster because they use many horses to keep up a high average speed/

Comment: Just want to point out that the Rokugan maps being accepted yet not always accurate matches historical maps of China (and sometimes Japan) which were generally accurate if you followed established routes, but not if you went off road. Also, some maps distorted sizes of cities and regions based on their population or importance (a [cartogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram)), making certain areas appear closer than they really were.